# what does "call the man who deals in love beyond repair" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

There is a song by "[Celine Dion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celine_Dion)" entitled "[Call the man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CelineDionCalltheMan.ogg)" in which she said somewhere "call the man who deals in love beyond repair". What does "who deals in love beyond repair" mean?

Comment: When something is "beyond repair" it is broken and cannot be repaired.

Comment: Thanks, for your attention. So now what does "**deals in love**" mean?

Comment: "deals in X" = has a business related to  X.

Comment: @TRomano, thanks for your help. based upon your comments I prepared an answer to close the question. If possible, please kindly approve it.

Comment: Anonim, only you can approve an answer to your own question. We can only comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this in one of the websites,i think it sums it up pretty well.....

Who else can "deal in love beyond repair?" Who is
the only one who can truly "heal a broken heart?"
Who else has walked with us "once upon a time"
and is with us in the present? Who leads us into the
future with his shining light? Who else could help
us in the "chaos and confusion" of this world? Who
else knows us so well and the trouble we get
ourselves into? Who else would be willing to help
us merely out of love for us and actually have
the power to do so? Who else has the power of God
except God? There is no other.

Can any love be beyond repair? It may seem true
when years of hurt, insensitivity and denial have
made both parties numb to their actual condition or
any attempts to salvage what is left. No major
difficulty can be resolved if the people involved
do not recognize a problem exists. (Even if you do
believe in fairies, magical solutions do not work
in times like these.) Situations also appear
irreparable when a couple does not work together.
A relationship does not exist in one person but
between two. When solving problems with a loved
one, the effort of one is similar to a dog chasing
its tail. If one walks away, the other is left with
nothing but an exercise in circular confusion.
People left behind get caught up in accusations
and possibilities. But no answers to the questions
of "What if?" or "Who did what?" will ever mend
these broken hearts. Of course, the illusion that
only one person is/was responsible may be the very
seed of destruction contained within these
questions.

What does it take to "heal a broken a heart?" I am
sure the answer to this question will be as varied
as the kind of hurts each heart sustains. The
betrayed wonder how they could have been such
fools. They question their powers of discernment
and their ability to trust again. The betrayers may
or may not have feelings of remorse. If their
pride makes them self righteous or self justified,
they will not heal. Their weakness is hidden from
God's healing power. Their hurts are buried alive
beneath the blame they give to the person. If they
do recognize their own guilt, they have need of
forgiveness from God, others and themselves.
Forgiving themselves is the hardest. Many at this
stage may question their own ability to do right or
even their ability to trust themselves again. If
both parties recognize their part in the breakdown
of the relationship, healing may mean more than
the willingness to care for the other again. It
also implies an openness to the possibility of
being hurt as well although hoping and trusting
that they won't.

Where is the way out of the "chaos and
confusion?" God "shines a light ahead when the
next step is unclear." The readiness to walk with
God is our only assurance of true peace now and in
the future. But "walking with God" means being with
God every step of the way. The "light of God"
illuminates the path, but we still must choose to
stay on it. Getting lost is as easy as taking our
eyes off of God and not watching where we are
going. Our destination may be unclear, but our
reaching it is certain if we trust in God. Believing
in God's love can increase our trust. Considering
the great personal sacrifice God has made on our
behalf, in Jesus, should tell us our best interests
are being cared for. And while the love of God
helps our faith, appreciating the power of God
will boost our confidence.

So,... "Call the man who deals in love beyond
repair. He can heal the world of hearts in need of
care. Shine a light ahead when the next step is
unclear. Call the man. He's needed here..."

Comment: But yours, anonim, was more concise—without waxing theological or trying to analyze other lyrics not cited. (Not that yours, Thule, wasn't beautiful, poetic and true.)

Answer (score 1):

So according to the comments mostly provided by @TRomano, I came up to this answer,

“**Call the man who deals in love beyond repair**” means

“**Call someone who is master in healing broken hearts which cannot be recovered by normal human beings' power. He has such a power to cure those broken hearts.**”

Maybe it is referring to **Jesus Christ**.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "broken heart" is used for the sadness after love affair ends. Some people say they are so sad that their broken heart will never recover, i.e. it can never be repaired. Perhaps the phrase in the question refers to a male relative or friend who has provided good advice in the past.

I think the phrase is associated with repairing a broken heart.

Comment: From the lyrics, "Call the man
 Who deals in once upon a time
 Maybe he
 Can mend this broken heart of mine"

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: you're no slouch.